# xbox one controller prevent default back button behavior with Javascript

Tags: javascript, xbox-one

I have an xbox one app that has a webview containing a javascript app.

In my React app I have something like this:

```
navigator.gamepadInputEmulation = 'gamepad';

window.addEventListener('onkeydown', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 196) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    // custom back button logic
  }
});
```

The custom back button logic runs but then the default controller back button logic also runs even with `event.stopImmediatePropagation();`  Is there any fix for this?

If I set `navigator.gamepadInputEmulation = 'keyboard';` this issue goes away but then all the controller input events run twice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick fix for you, just intercept the 'backrequested' and set it as handled:

```
var systemNavManager = Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.getForCurrentView();
systemNavManager.addEventListener("backrequested", (event)=>event.handled = true, false);
```

Hope that helps!