# UWP - Xbox One - JavaScript - disable gamepadB default back navigation behaviour

Tags: javascript, uwp, xbox

I have a pure JavaScript/React bundled pwa/hosted web app running on Xbox One.
The app has its own custom navigation.
I want to disable gamepadB default history.goBack() behaviour.

As per

[xbox one controller prevent default back button behavior with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56981247/xbox-one-controller-prevent-default-back-button-behavior-with-javascript)

something like this should work, but it doesn't:

```js
navigator.gamepadInputEmulation = "keyboard";
if (typeof Windows !== "undefined") {
  const systemNavManager = Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.getForCurrentView();

  if (systemNavManager) {
    systemNavManager.addEventListener(
      'backrequested',
      event => {
        event.handled = true;
      },
      false
    );
  }
}
```

setting event.handled in capture/bubble phase does nothing. event.handled is already set to true before this handler is called.
Using:

```js
event.preventDefault()
```

will crash the app as standard dom functionalities like
preventDefault, stopPropagation, and stopImmediatePropagation are not supported.

[BackRequestedEventArgs Class | Windows Dev Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.backrequestedeventargs?view=winrt-19041)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out, just adding e.preventDefault() on a keydown event where the keyCode is gamepadB will stop the default system back navigation

```
navigator.gamepadInputEmulation = "keyboard";

document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
            if (e.keyCode === 196 // 196 is the keycode for B button on gamepad) {

                e.preventDefault();
                this.handleBack(e);
            }
        });
```